# How do I manipulate object.style.animationDuration outside of Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, css-animations

I know that throwing the webkit prefix at the start works for Chrome (as `object.style.webkitAnimationDuration`), but I have yet to find any way of making this work with the Opera prefix, and I'm not sure how effective the Firefox prefix is either. W3Schools say that all the major browsers support the duration property, so what do I do?

Jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4C7Fp/

Javascript and Jquery suggestions accepted :)

Comment: Your code already works in Firefox. It doesn't work in IE10 however, and I can't test Opera. There are no other prefixes anyhow, the two you've used cover all the major browsers.

Comment: Well, regardless of prefices is still doesn't work in Opera or IE10 - Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this plugin for that. ([Prefixfree Plugin](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/)) It has also jquery plugin to set/get css without prefixes.

Btw why didnt you use it in css? It can be better and faster than javascript.

Comment: The duration is pegged to the duration of audio.duration (I'm making a custom audio control).

Comment: I'll try to use that plugin when I can. Thanks :)

Comment: Well, I reloaded the document after attaching prefixfree, and nothing changed. I suspect that Opera doesn't support object.animationDuration - do you know how true this is?